# Xcode build fails second time with `cycle inside` error, complaining about GLFW lib

Tags: c++, xcode, glfw, vulkan

I am following the tutorial for Vulkan at vulkan-tutorial.com. When I make a change to my source, then build the project, it will run without issue. When I stop it and then press run again, the build fails due to a cycle inside the project. It says that there is a copy command from the GLFW libraryy to xcode derived data project info, and a link command with output in the same place:

`Target has copy command from '/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/HEAD-76406c7/lib/libglfw.3.4.dylib' to '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CPP_TEST-gkvulchjoosihwdcfhpftbezlfwh/Build/Products/Debug/libglfw.3.4.dylib'`

`Target has link command with output '/Users/sebastianwilkinson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CPP_TEST-gkvulchjoosihwdcfhpftbezlfwh/Build/Products/Debug/CPP_TEST'`

I have installed GLFW using homebrew. I have a link to the library in the build phases link with libraries. The copy files phase is then set to framework, no subpath, and don't copy only when installing, and the GLFW library is linked in using the default method to add. I also have header and library search paths set up.

I have tried deleting the DerivedData folder. This works temporarily, allowing me to build without changing the code and without failing, but as soon as I change the code, it builds once then fails.

I experimented to reproduce the error, creating a new project called CPP_TEST, only adding the GLFW library and search paths setup. I then add `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` to the top of the default main.cpp file, and build a couple of times, and the error occurs.

I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.3 with the latest version of Xcode.